# Android Intent provided to searchable Activity before Fragments are created?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a `FragmentActivity` defined in my `searchable.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml` as the go-to handler for any search queries.

Here's what works:

1) The user clicks the search button, enters some text, and executes the search

2) My searchable Activity's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method is called (its `launchMode` is `singleTop`)

3) Calling `getIntent()` in the `onCreate()` method gives me a proper `android.intent.action.SEARCH` action, with the query!

**Here's what doesn't work:**

At the end of `onCreate()`, I want to update all my child fragment activities - the main searchable has 4 swipeable tabs at the top, to switch between 4 different `ListView` views based on category.

The problem, is that `onCreateView()` is not called on my child `Fragment` views until *after* the `onCreate()` in my main activity is finished. So my `ListView` objects don't even exist yet!

So, I need to either:

1) Cache the results of my `handleIntent()` method that does the querying and result-gathering, and access them in the `Fragment` when it finally loads, or:

2) Find some way to trigger these `Fragment` views to load in the parent `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method so that I can actually provide them the data they should be displaying.

Was I incorrect in assuming that these child `Fragment`s would be ready to go at the end of the parent `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method?

**Relevant code:**

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
   ...
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating view with section number: " + getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
   ...
   }
}
```

And in my `SearchActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    setTitle("Search Items");

    // Here the pager and adapter are created - this is
    // boilerplate code created by the Android Eclipse plugin
    ...

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}
```

Finally, the `handleIntent()` method, which performs the updating:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Handling intent: " + intent.getAction());
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        // Perform the search!
        List<String> results = ...;

        DummySectionFragment allItemsFragment = (DummySectionFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);

        allItemsFragment.refreshWithItems(results);
    }
}
```

In the `refreshWithItems()` method, the `Fragment` just checks to see if `getView()` is available, which it is **not**.

In the log, I see:

```
01-31 18:02:52.981: I/com.mycompany.myapp.SearchActivity(1595): Handling intent: android.intent.action.SEARCH
01-31 18:03:00.221: I/com.mycompany.myapp.SearchActivity(1595): Creating view with section number: 1
01-31 18:03:00.241: I/com.mycompany.myapp.SearchActivity(1595): Creating view with section number: 2
```

Thus confirming that the views are created *after* I'm expected to have handled the `Intent` and query.

Comment: what if you initialize all you need in onResume of you main activity?

Comment: @Tobiel That's what I ended up doing - worked well.